# Using Animation for Clip, RectangleGeometry, and Rect

Tags: xaml, animation, geometry, clip, rect

I want to use Animation & Storyboards for the Clip property of some of the elements in my XAML. However, I have been unable to find a way to do this. As you probably know, the Clip property is a RectangleGeometry, and I need to use Animation for the RectangleGeometry.Rect.Y and RectangleGeometry.Rect.Height properties. The Clip property that I am trying to animate is the Clip property of a Popup, for which I also need to animate the VerticalOffset property. Is there a way to use Animation for these things? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you working in? WPF, SL, UWP, WP? What have you tried? I normally wouldn't recommend this sort of thing as it's likely a performance hit.

Comment: I am currently using UWP. I managed to solve the VerticalOffset by setting DoubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation=True, but I still haven't found a solution for Popup.Clip.Rect